# How to display in the nightwatch.js report all the outputs that appears in the console

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

In some nightwatch.js tests I use console.log to print some variables values or comments. I would like to know if there is a way to print the console.log of the console in a nightwatch.js report since only nightwatch commands/assertions are visible.
**What I want to do is to display a report that contains all results like when I run the test in the console.**
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Most of the command has msg(optional) parameter,

```
    this.demoTest = function (browser) {
             const msg = "We have passed the test"
             browser.assert.visible(".testElement",msg);

        };
```

Instead of

```
v Testing if .testElement is visible
```

It will print

```
v We have passed the test
```

or

```
 x We have passed the test
```

Comment: In this the case would work as a comment bu for example, `.getAttribute('#register-form > .box div:nth-child(6)','textContent', function (name){
                        if( i == 1){
                            console.log('--> First click done on ' + name.value);
                            browser.getAttribute('.subscription-total','textContent', function (kz){
                                console.log(kz.value);
                            })
                        }` this console.log will depend on the name.value and the kz.value

Comment: your answer will help I when I want to write a comment but If I want to print some name/word  from the portal, that will not work. Is there any Nightwatch.js command to substitute the `console.log('msg');` ?

Comment: The example isn't exactly correct.  In the case of a failed assertion, the output will look like this ...
× my custom message in 5000ms - expected "is visible" but got: "element could not be located" (5185ms)